# LibGDX/OpenGL - glReadPixels Transparency Issue

Tags: opengl, libgdx, alpha-transparency, glreadpixels

I have a problem with glReadPixels/ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap() where semi-transparent sprites drawn on top of opaque ones seem to "overwrite" the transparency, resulting in a mess.

Black sprites with 10% transparency are drawn on top of the tiles to look like shadows.

Original (in-game) image:

[image: Normal shadows.]

Image obtained with glReadPixels in ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(...):

[image]

(the shadows are white because they're slightly transparent)

How would I make alpha blending work properly in getFrameBufferPixmap()?

Comment: You need to drop the alpha-channel in your result (i.e. set alpha to 1.0f for all pixels), thats whats OpenGL does when presenting the image on the screen. Alpha is stored in the intermediate result because its needed for alpha-calculations when you draw on top of already-drawn pixels.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that. Changing each pixel alpha to 1 seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `glBlendFuncSeparate` instead of `glBlendFunc`, which is what SpriteBatch uses. SpriteBatch provides a back door (undocumented I think for some reason) for using `glBlendFuncSeparate`. Set it's blend function parameters to -1, and then you can manually set your own `glBlendFuncSeparate` that always leaves the alpha of your frame buffer as 1.0:

```
spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(-1, -1);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFuncSeparate(
    GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_ONE);
//...
spriteBatch.begin();
//...
spriteBatch.end();
```

Also make sure the alpha of your `glClearColor` is `1.0f`.

Comment: Hmmm, that just seems to disable the shadows completely.

Comment: How are you drawing shadows currently? What blend func, and what is the sprite like? (opaque sprite with reduced alpha sprite batch, or translucent sprite)

Comment: I was drawing opaque sprites and changing the batch alpha. Apparently, all I needed to do with the pixmaps is process them and set the alpha of each pixel to 0, and it looked fine.